# Table of Contents is not generated

Tags: adobe-indesign

In a InDesign document, I have various Headings and would like to generate a TOC. This worked in the beginning but after some restructuring of the document, it no longer works. It only writes the header but all other content is missing.

One of the things I did change is the frame, the TOC should get generated in.

Does anyone know how to analyze, what the problem is or how to solve this?

Comment: Did you chance the paragraph style the headings use? The TOC is generally constructed by finding specific paragraph styles and using those as TOC items. If you changed styles, you need to verify the generator is looking for the new style, not the old style.

Comment: No, I did not change the paragraph style of the headings and I also double checked and I think the settings should be correct.

Comment: Try to put the TOC in a new frame. Do not ask me why, but that has sometimes solved a similar problem for me.

Comment: @boblet Tried that now, too but no difference in behavior. The strange thing is I see no markup of the TOC in the Story Editor. Is this correct?

Comment: Hm, I am not an InDesign expert, so the only thing I can think of, is that the headings in your document somehow is not registered as headings any more. Highlight one, and see if it shows up as heading1, heading2 or somesuch.

Comment: @boblet no that works fine. I fear it might be some kind of weird InDesign bug. Not sure what to do though, since I do not have the time to redo my document.

Comment: Have you tried doing a new document, with just a few lines and a couple of headings; just to see?

Comment: Yes, just tried with an old backup of the document and there it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is frightening.
What I did is create a new page before the content and then link that page to the already present thread. And now it works again.

Comment: Glad you sorted it. You can accept your own answer as the solution. Would be good for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

baffling and bizarre - but linking an empty text frame at the beginning of the already formatted text cleared up what ever indesign's issue was with only building the title and not the rest of the contents. Before that I kept getting the message 'update table of contents' when I had yet to create it. This was a base used for a previous (and similar) project.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue – an older document, restructured and updated also generated just the contents header. I went to Layout > Table of Contents Styles (where I had some styles saved from the previous version of the doc) and deleted the styles. Then I updated the TOC and everything displayed perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't done a TOC in a while and had this issue too. Not sure yet whether I screwed something up or if it's like this by default, but all of my included paragraph styles had a hierarchy Level set to zero. I made sure they were set to level 1 or 2 as needed and it generated.